# Securing Apache With Systemd

Tags: apache2, systemd

I am trying to secure Apache in a webhosting environment on ubuntu 20.04 server using systemd.  My question is:  How do i set a variable in path for usernames:

For a single user this works:

```
ProtectSystem=strict
ReadWritePaths=/var/log/apache2/
ReadWritePaths=/var/run
ReadWritePaths=/home/testuser/public_html
ProtectHome=tmpfs
BindPaths=/home/testuser/public_html
```

How do I get something like the following to work:

```
ProtectSystem=strict
ReadWritePaths=/var/log/apache2/
ReadWritePaths=/var/run
ReadWritePaths=/home/$USER/public_html
ProtectHome=tmpfs
BindPaths=/home/$USER/public_html
```

thanks

Comment: You won't be able to pull `$USER` into Apache in these cases, because that's not an env variable that's accepted even if you include an environment file.  AppArmor is better designed for these types of configurations, rather than using SystemD to lock it down you might want to look into building an apparmor profile for your deployment that allows the proper access to other directories and rejects others.

Comment: drats... foiled again!  :-) thanks for the feedback.